# Editing Placeholderleftnavbar (Master) - removing linkable text

Tags: 2010

I am trying to edit the PlaceHolderLeftNavBar (Master). There is a list of links within in and some of the links are pointing to the wrong places. I need to go in there and remove/edit some of those links. As of right now all I can do is select the section. How can I edit the text within the nav bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the quick launch nav (which i think you are), in the main these links are managed in your SP navigation, which you can access from the following:

[image: quick launch nav]

Site settings > Look and feel > Navigation > Navigation Editing and Sorting

If you need to manage the recycle bin and all site content links you can control these via CSS.

Hope this helps.

S

Comment: Awesome, thanks that did the trick. On a side note...any way to get the now unlinked headers to not have "hoverbility".

Comment: Yes you can do that through CSS alone. Could you mark this answer up?